# Android Service called two times wrongly with one StartService method

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The following code, which works normally, suddently print the message below two times wrongly:

```
MainApplicationService started
MyMessagemessage received

MainApplicationService started
MyMessagemessage received
```

The code below:

```
  [Activity(Label = "My app", MainLauncher = true, Name = "com.myapp.StartupActivity")]
    public class StartupActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainApplicationService));

            StartService(serviceIntent);

            Finish();
        }
    }

[Service(Name = "com.myapp.MainApplicationService", Label = "Main Application Service", Exported = false)]
    public class MainApplicationService : Service
    {
        private IDeviceLog _logger;

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            _logger = Ioc.Container.Resolve<IDeviceLog>();
            _logger.Info("MainApplicationService started");
             var worker = Ioc.Container.Resolve<IWorker>();
            Task.Run(async () => await worker.Init());

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    }

    public class Worker:IWorker {           
      private async Task Init(){

      _deviceLog.Info($"{nameof(MyMessagemessage)} received");  //called two times wrongly

      }
  }
```

After the app was restarted, the message is printed once, like below

```
MainApplicationService started
MyMessagemessage received
```

Xamarin Android, Android Lollipop

Answer (score 1):

The system may destroy the service due to insufficient memory, if this happens, the system will rebuild the service as soon as possible.You could define a state for a service in your  `OnStartCommand` like :

```
private bool isStarted;

public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (isStarted)
        {
            // service is already started
        }
        else
        {
            _logger = Ioc.Container.Resolve<IDeviceLog>();
            _logger.Info("MainApplicationService started");
            var worker = Ioc.Container.Resolve<IWorker>();
            Task.Run(async () => await worker.Init());
            isStarted = true;
        }
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

Comment: Does the system destroy the whole app or just the service in the app, `MainApplicationService` in this case? Because there are other classes in the app which are singleton. Ideally, the whole app is destroyed and restarted? How to restart the app programmatically if that is not the case?

Comment: Even it is only the service that gets destroyed, you code still reference the service. How is it possible?

Comment: If it happens,it will detroy the `MainApplicationService` and then recreate it.That's my guess, you could try it out like above , see if it will be called twice again ?

Comment: As you mentioned, 'If it happens,it will detroy the MainApplicationService and then recreate it.', how can your code still use `isStarted` within `MainApplicationService`?

Comment: When the service is stopped, and restarted again, will your code work?

Comment: @Pingpong I could not produce your issue and it was called once.Could you share your test project ?

Comment: The main code has been shared on the opening post, which is a simpilfied version from the original version. I cannot share the original version. But I hope answer can be given based on the OP.

Comment: I could not produce the issue.Did you call StartService anywhere else ？

Comment: I only get it once, which I cannot reproduce it now. It is random error.